# Shortest paths with 2 constraints (Weight and Colour)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

**Input:** We have a directed graph G=(V,E) and each edge has a weight and a colour {red,green}. We are also given a starting node s.
**Problem/Algorithm:** Can we find for all u edges of G, the shortest paths s-u with at most k red edges ?
 **First approach:** We save for each node the shortest path with 0,1...k red edges. We modify Dijkstra's algorithm and depending on the colour of the edges we are looking into, we update the distances respectively. This approach fails due to its complexity.
 **Second approach:** We make k copies of G graph (G1,G2 ...Gk+1). In order to utilise the k red edges constraint, while we are searching for shortest paths with Dijkstra, every time we "meet" a red edge {ui,vi} in Gi, we connect ui with vi+1 in Gi+1. Because Gk+1 doesn't have any red edges, we can only reach Gk+1 with at most k edges.But it fails. For example with k=2 if a 2 red edges shortest path is found to X node then will not take into consideration a heavier path with less red edges which could lead to an undiscovered node. (If i had enough reputation i could post an image as example). 
Any ideas ?

Comment: I think your approaches are actually equivalent, and they are (both) sound.  In particular, your reasoning that approach #2 is faulty is itself wrong: for any node X in the original graph, there is no single corresponding node X in the new graph; instead there are separate vertices for each number of red edges used.  So the two paths you are considering are not actually to the same node: one is to (X, 2 red edges use) and one is to e.g. (X, 1 red edge used).

Comment: I mean that the approaches are equivalent if, for approach #1, you record only *the shortest distance to* each node for each number of red edges used.  You don't need to record the entire path (just as you don't need to record it for ordinary Dijkstra on an ordinary shortest path problem).

Comment: So i can consider any new node i duplicate as a new one which i should check separately. At the end of the  algorithm, in order to find the shortest path, i should check every duplicated node which corresponds to the same initial one ?

Comment: Yes.  Also you need to make sure that for any red edge {u, v} in G, you *delete* the corresponding edge {ui, vi} for all Gi (as well as add in the edge {ui, vi+1}).  You probably intended this, but you weren't explicit about it.

Comment: Thanks sir, you helped me a lot. I wish i could give you reputation :D

Comment: You're welcome :)  I wrote it up as an answer, in case your urge to upvote is strong ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approaches are actually equivalent, provided that for approach #1, you record only *the shortest distance to* each node for each number of red edges used -- you don't need to record the entire path (just as you don't need to record it for ordinary Dijkstra on an ordinary shortest path problem)

Also this approach is sound.  In particular, your reasoning that approach #2 is faulty is itself wrong: for any node X in the original graph, there is no single corresponding node X in the new graph; instead there are separate vertices for each number of red edges used. So the two paths "to X" you are considering are not actually to the same node: one is to (X, 2 red edges used) and one is to e.g. (X, 1 red edge used).  Then you can use a single Dijkstra run to calculate shortest paths to all k+1 copies of every vertex (i.e. to the vertices (v, i red edges used) for each 0 <= i <= k and for each v in V(G)), and return the lowest.  (I'm assuming here that when you wrote "Can we find for all u edges of G, the shortest paths s-u", you meant "for all *nodes* u of G, the shortest paths s-u".)

Finally, you need to make sure that for any red edge {u, v} in G, you delete the corresponding edge {ui, vi} for all Gi (as well as add in the edge {ui, vi+1}). You probably intended this, but you weren't explicit about it.